# Converting Datetime to Time(DateTime) in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Good day,

I have a **Time(DateTime)** field in my **SQL Server DB** Table and I have to commit a record with a **DateTime** type on VS 2010 program to my DB. When I do I am getting the following error:

{"A column insert or update conflicts with a rule imposed by a previous CREATE RULE statement. The statement was terminated. The conflict occurred in database 'PTBODW', table 'dbo.**MatchGPStoTripSchedule**', column '**tTripScheduledStartTime**'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."} can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it may be a variable out of range. I'd fire up SQL profiler in SQL management studio and find the exact SQL that is causing the error. If its a bulk insert, I'd sucessively have the size of the insert until you isolat the (first?) row causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the column is using [the old `sp_bindrule` feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176063.aspx).  You can list the rules in your database with:

```
select  o.name as TableName
,       c.name as ColumnName
,       r.name as RuleName
from    sys.objects o
join    sys.columns c
on      c.object_id = o.object_id
join    sys.objects r
on      r.object_id = c.rule_object_id
where   o.is_ms_shipped <> 1
        and rule_object_id <> 0
```

You can view the definition of a rule with `sp_helptext`:

```
exec sp_helptext 'RuleName'
```

Rules can be unbound from a column with `sp_unbindrule` (there can only be one rule per column, so `sp_unbindrule` does not need to know the rule's name):

```
exec sp_unbindrule 'MatchGPStoTripSchedule.tTripScheduledStartTime'
```

Comment: I am using MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 and the query you posted does not give me results, may be I am using a wrong db, which db must i use?

Comment: From the error message in your post, I guess you should be looking in `PTBODW` ?